# How to create an Outlook .msg file with Redemption C# that has an HTML body?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I can't seem to get any formatting when creating a HTML format .msg file.  The text shows up in the body but the HTML formatting is not applied. Any suggestions?

```
RDOSession rdoSession = new RDOSession();
rdoSession.Logon();

// Start with a seed.msg
File.Copy(@".\seed.msg", @".\test.msg", true);
RDOMail rdoMail = rdoSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(@".\test.msg", false);
// Set body format to HTML
rdoMail.BodyFormat = 2;
rdoMail.Subject = "HTML format test";
rdoMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body><b>bold</b> text</body></html>";
// PR_InetMailOverrideFormat  
rdoMail.set_Fields(0x59020003, 0x00020000 | 0x00100000 | 0x00040000);
// PR_MSG_EDITOR_FORMAT
rdoMail.set_Fields(0x59090003, 2);
rdoMail.Save();
```

Comment: What version of Redemption are you using?

Comment: v.5.16.0.4972, but I also downloaded the latest developer version 5.23 and tried that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are opening an existing MSG file instead of creating a new one. I had no problem with the following script executed from OutlookSpy (I am its author) - click “Script Editor” button on the OutlookSpy toolbar, paste the script, click Run:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
set rdoMail = Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\html.msg")
rdoMail.Subject = "HTML format test"
rdoMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body><b>bold</b> text</body></html>"
rdoMail.Save
```

Comment: No problem with the script but I get the same results as before. There is no formatting in the resulting file.  i.e., the word bold is not **bold**.  I also discovered that if I use this ("<html><body><b>bold</b> text<p>another line of text</p></body></html>") as the HTMLBody that the "another line of text" does not display in the resulting file.

Comment: Hmmm.. Can you create a script that does exhibit the problem?

Comment: Yes. The script you provided exhibits the problem.

Comment: Can you zip the resulting MSG file and send it to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com?

Comment: This works in 5.23.  I failed to register the v5.23 Redemption.dll properly when I tried it with that version. Thanks for all the help!